# Operator '==' not applying to custom type C++

Tags: c++, chess

I am working on a chess game in C++, and each type of piece has its own class, which all inherit the "Space" class. For the board, I have an two dimensional 8x8 array of Space, declared as `Space board[8][8] {}` the brackets being filled with different instances of the piece classes.

I need to make an `if` statement to check if a space is empty. This means, I need to check a location on the array if it is empty. The current code for the if statement is

```
if(board[0][0] == wRook1 {}
```

Please note: `wRook1` is an instance of the Rook class, which inherits the Space class. However, I get an error saying that the

> operator == is not valid for the operands Space == Space.

How do I make the custom class `Space` work with the == operator?

Currently the Space class simply has a constructor, as it is only used to be an overarching type for the pieces.

Comment: You define `operator==`...

Answer (score 1):

The comparison operator can be virtual:

```
struct Base { virtual bool operator==(const Base &) const = 0; };
```

A typical implementation would check for type identity first, and then for object identity:

```
struct A : Base
{
    bool operator==(const Base & rhs) const override
    {
        if (auto * p = dynamic_cast<const A *>(&rhs))
        {
            return typeid(*p) == typeid(A) && /* compare value */;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // state
};
```

The inner type check is necessary to exclude the case where `rhs` is contained in an object *derived from* `A` rather than of type `A` exactly. You could spare yourself this extra check if `A` was `final`. You could alternatively start with the `typeid` check, but you generally still need the dynamic cast (rather than a static cast) in case the base is virtual.

Comment: [Demo](https://ideone.com/DwluGM)

Comment: Would I place this within the class? Within the cpp file or header file? In the constructor?

Comment: @Zuve: Whichever you like. It's just like an ordinary class member function. You have to define an override in every derived class.